# Is this trigonometric equation solvable?

Tags: trigonometry

The equation is this:
$$x  \sin(x) = 90 - x$$
I've tried to solve it myself, to no avail. After that, I went to a bunch of algebraic equations solvers, which gave me differing results. Is this equation solvable? By solving, I mean finding a definitive numerical answer for the variable x. If it is, then what is the answer (and steps), and if not, why not?

Comment: see here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xsinx%3D90-x

Comment: Is $x$ the angle in radians or degrees?

Comment: It's in radians

Comment: What do you mean for the equation to be solvable?

Comment: For there to be a definitive way to solve for the variable 'x'

Comment: @recursiverecursion You should add that information to the question. As it stands in could be interpreted in at least two others ways. One of them being if the equation as any solution, while the other is numerically finding the solution.

Comment: @recursiverecursion I didn't make myself clear. In mathematics, 'numerically' means by approximation. For instance someone might tell you that the solution is $x\approx 45.8217$. I suggest you ask 'how to solve for $x$' (which I believe is what you want), then someone will tell you it can't be done.

Comment: In my answer I assumed that the angle was in degrees. You can do the same in radians

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the angles are in degrees. Using Newton's method  I get 
$x=50.7284012596462$

Here is what I did. 
First I wrote your equation in terms of radians as
$$
f(x)=
(180 \cdot x\sin(x))/\pi+(180 x)/\pi-90=0$$
Derivative of $f(x)$ is given by
$$f'(x)=180(\sin(x)+x \cos(x)+1)$$

Now define a new function
$$h(x) = x  - f(x)/f'(x)$$

starting with $x=0$, I repeatedly applied $h$ to get
$$
h(0) = 1.570796326794897\\
h(1.570796326794897) = 0.78539816339745 \\
h(0.78539816339745) = 0.88707380376403 \\
h(0.88707380376403) = 0.88537798182847 \\
h(0.88537798182847) = 0.88537762625368 \\
h(0.88537762625368) = 0.88537762625367\\
h(0.88537762625367)=0.88537762625367
$$
Note how the numbers change very little. I stopped when there was no visible change to get
the answer in radians as $0.88537762625367$ or in degrees 
$$
0.88537762625367 * 180/\pi = 50.72840125964648^\circ
$$

After I posted the reply I saw the OP's clarification that the angles are in radians. The same approach works with
$$
f(x) = x\sin(x)+x-90, ~f'(x)=1+\sin x + x \cos x, ~h(x) = x - f(x)/f'(x)$$
to get
$x = 91.11846207528532$ as the final answer.

Comment: If you plug this back into the equation, it does not appear to be correct.

Comment: It does, try it.

Comment: Sorry, I was using radians with your degrees answer. I'd never heard of Newton's method before. It appears very useful!

Comment: Newton's method is the only general purpose tool we have. Unfortunately, if a  problem has more than one solution, Newton's method can give you any of them unless you start close to the one you want. I just started the answer at 0. If you start at 45, you get $45.37179851005318$

Answer (score 2):

Graphing such a function is always helpful: for one, it can verify that one or more solutions *exit*. (Otherwise, if no solution exists, we certainly don't want to waste time trying to find one!)

See, for example, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xsinx%3D90-x), where you can see the graphs of $y = 90-x$ and $y = x\sin(x)$, and the points of intersection (i.e., solutions): As you see, there are many solutions satisfying the given equation.

[image]

You can then use *[Newton's Method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/NewtonsMethod.aspx)* to *approximate* the solution(s), but we cannot pin down, definitively, the value(s) of any solution(s).

Comment: Needs an UV for nice graphic and links to method +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Newton's tangent method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to approximate the solutions.